# Number of ways n can be written as sum of at least two positive integers

Tags: algorithms, number-theory, integer-partitions

I found a solution in Python for this problem, but do not understand it. The problem is how many ways an integer n can be written as the sum of at least two positive integers. For example, take n = 5. The number 5 can be written as

```
4 + 1
3 + 2
3 + 1 + 1
2 + 2 + 1
2 + 1 + 1 + 1
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
```

Here's a solution for given $n$.

```
# zero-based array (first index is 0)
ways = [1, 0, ..., 0] (n zeroes)

for i in 1, ..., n-1:
    for j in i, ..., n:
        ways[j] = ways[j] + ways[j-i]

print ways[n]
```

This solution is elegant and efficient, but unfortunately, I do not understand the logic. Can someone please explain the logic of this solution to the problem? Is there a way to make this algorithm easy to understand?

Comment: I think the solution is using dynamic programming (tabulation).

Comment: My post is quite similar to yours. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/118809/leetcode-combinatorial-sum-how-to-generate-solution-set-from-number-of-solut

Answer (score 2):

Let us denote the array *ways* after $t$ iterations of the outer loop by $w_t$. The recurrence implemented by the code is
$$
w_0(n) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } n = 0, \\
0 & \text{if } n > 0.
\end{cases} \\
w_t(n) = \begin{cases}
w_{t-1}(n) & \text{if } n < t, \\
w_{t-1}(n) + w_t(n-t) & \text{if } n \geq t.
\end{cases}
$$
You can prove by induction that $w_t(n)$ is the number of representations of $n$ as a sum of natural numbers between $1$ and $t$ (without regard to order). (This is also the number of representations of $n$ as a sum of at most $t$ natural numbers.)

The code returns $w_{n-1}(n)$, which is the number of representations of $n$ as an arbitrary sum of natural numbers, other than the representation $n$.

As an aside, if you allow the trivial representation then you get the [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)). Using Rademacher's asymptotic formula, the partition function can be computed in time $\tilde O(\sqrt{n})$, much faster than your $\Theta(n^2)$ algorithm.

Comment: "This is also the number of representations of $n$ as a sum of at most $t$ natural numbers"

Is this intuitively equivalent to the number of partitions of $n$ to numbers at most $t$ (the statement to prove with induction)? I don't quite see the relation between both statements.

Comment: Conjugation moves you from one to the other. Look it up.

Comment: I was able to prove the statement by proving that the number representations of $n$ as a sum of exactly  $t$ numbers is equal to the number of representations of $n-t$ as a sum of at most $t$ numbers.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Conjugate_and_self-conjugate_partitions.

Comment: However, I couldn't find resources about the conjugation you mentioned above (there were many different "kinds" of conjugation in wikipedia and I didn't know which one did you mean)